# Singularity access files on host on %post

Tags: docker, conda, singularity-container

I am using singularity to create a python environment with Conda and need to access an .yml file in the def script. How can you access them ?

Answer (score 2):

Add an instruction to the `%files` section of your def file to copy the .yml file from your build context (directory containing the def file) before the portion of the def file that runs the conda command:

```
%files
    /your.yaml /location/in/image_filesystem/your.yaml
```

Comment: In addition you can bind host directories and mount them onto subdirectories in the container using the --bind option in singularity build